# Is it possible to render a part twice in one display type? - Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

I have a content type, Events, that has a part "StartDate" that I need to show twice in the summary view. Is it possible inside placement.info to render the part in "this" zone AND "that" zone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Render the zone twice

Probably not through just using the `placement.info` file but if you edit the `.cshtml` view you can just render a zone twice.

For a test I just edited my blog detail view to have this code:

```
    @Display(Model.Content)
    @Display(Model.Content)
```

It worked, and displayed it twice. It's something you should probably be careful with this as in that example it rendered out my Disqus comments twice which created a clash because the same id was used twice on a single page.

### Fine tune it with Part Relocation

If you need to pull a single bit of content (a shape/part) out of an existing zone you can also do it with something called Part Relocation which is explained in this [Orchard Harvest Session](https://youtu.be/gKLjtCIs4GU?t=56m47s).

The basic idea is to use placement to isolate it into its own zone:

```
<Match ContentType="News" DisplayType="Detail">
    <Place Parts_StartDate="MakeUpAZoneName" />
</Match>
```

(Note: the `Match` tag is just an example, its the `Place` you will need to put in whatever match you want)

And then you can render that out in your .cshtml file with `@Display()` like:

```
@Display(Model.MakeUpAZoneName)

... other html code ...

@Display(Model.MakeUpAZoneName)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't render same shape twice, but simply you can return combined shapes from your driver and render each shape in different zone.

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible, Only the first one in the file `placement.info` works.